# When the mobile authenticator requires logging in again?

Tags: steam

I had to perform a factory reset on my phone and restored the Steam application from a backup (Android) as I've done successfully a couple of times, but now the app prompted me to log in again and I received a week-long community market cooldown as a result.

How does the application determine that it has been installed on a new device? Do I periodically have to re-enter my account credentials? How can I avoid re-authentication (and related account restrictions)?

Comment: I don't know if we are really at liberty to speak for this.  It seems to be about the design of their application, which we really don't have a way of knowing.

Comment: I've had the app prompt me to log in again without even doing the factory reset (or any other unusual shenanigans besides normal syncing.)  I believe there's a known issue about that over on the Steam forums, and generally just closing the app and reopening it will make it realize you're logged in

Comment: @Steve-O: This may be what happened and I recall I've performed the same procedure to fix the issue — sadly I didn't remember to try on this time.

Answer (score 2):

We can only guess what happened, it's possible that factory reset counts as transferring to new device:

> After transferring the authenticator, any new trades or market listings will be held for a couple of days to protect your items in case your authenticator is ever transferred by a malicious person

Good sources of information could be official Steam Support Articles: [Steam Guard](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=8625-wrah-9030) and [Steam Trade Holds](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=8078-TPHC-6195).

Comment: As I said I've performed factory reset some times before and restored the Steam app without being logged out, but thank you for the official support articles.